# Remove Element - is not expected return type integer

Tags: python

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwKU6.png)

Can someone explains why my answer is not expected return type integer?

Why isn't 'nums' the expected return type of integer when all I do is modify 'nums'?

modify my code
my concept [Remove each element and reevaluate the list until all elements matching 'val' are removed.]

Comment: You even have a `List` type hint for `nums`, why would you expect it to be integer? you can also see in the stacktrace it's a list `[2, 2]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code, sample input, expected output and actual output as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You've confused yourself by attempting unnecessary recursion.

If you try to remove something from a list that doesn't exist you will get a ValueError exception. Therefore you can repeatedly call list.remove() until that situation arises.

Something like this:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
        while True:
            try:
                nums.remove(val)
            except ValueError:
                break
        return len(nums)
```

Another approach is to use a list comprehension to build a new list that does not contain any occurrences of *val* then copy that into the original list as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
        nums[:] = [n for n in nums if n != val]
        return len(nums)
```

The second approach appears to run faster than the first

Answer (score 0):

You got this error

> TypeError: [2, 2] is not valid value for the expected return type integer [] raise

because in the function you are returning the `nums` not the length of nums `len(nums)`

Try this

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
        print(nums)
        count = 0
        for i in nums:
            if i == val:
                count = count+1
        if count==0:
            return len(nums) # change nums to len(nums)
        else:
            for i in nums:
                if i == val:
                    nums.remove(i)
                    # break   # remove break from here
            return self.removeElement(nums, val)
```

---

Shorter version of your code is this

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
        # print(nums)
        count = 0
        for i in nums:
            if i == val:
                count = count+1
                nums.remove(i)
        return len(nums)
```